# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'AAAR78509883' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, type-conversion

I have a `nvarchar` column in one of my tables that I have imported from Access. I am trying to change to an int. To move to a new table.

The original query:

```
insert into members_exams_answer
    select 
        ua.members_exams_id, ua.exams_questions_id, 
        ua.members_exams_answers_value, ua.members_exams_answers_timestamp
    from 
        members_exams as me 
    full join 
        UserAnswers1 as ua on me.members_exams_username = ua.members_exams_id
    full join 
        exams_questions as eq on eq.exams_questions_id = ua.exams_questions_id
```

This throws an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'AAAR78509883' to data type int.

I have tired:

```
select convert (int, UserAnswers1.members_exams_id)
from UserAnswers1
```

and

```
select cast(members_exams_id as integer) int_members_exams_id
from UserAnswers1
```

and

```
select cast (members_exams_id as int)
from UserAnswers1
```

All result in the same error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'AAAR78509883' to data type int.

Comment: Well that's not an int. Are you expecting it to strip out the leading alpha characters?

Comment: Just trim the first 4 and then cast or convert to an int.  Otherwise you might want to explain why you're keeping the letters and what you want done with them.

Comment: Yep, can't have text characters in an int field, you'll have to think about that one.

Comment: I know that Visual Basic used to let you use `val()` to get a numeric value this way. I'm betting that Access does too and that's what you're used to.

Comment: @shawnt00 `Val()` in Visual Basic can trim trailing non-digits (`val("1234sdf") = 1234`). It will not try to remove leading non-digits.

Comment: @GSerg You're right. I haven't done BASIC in so long I couldn't remember whether it was front or back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could be systemic where all data has a leading alpha characters that you need to strip out (and hopefully the same number of alpha characters)

In that case use a substring to strip off the alphas (this assumes the name number of alphabetic characters in each record). Or use a varchar or nvarchar field instead of an int. If the number of leading characters varies or if they can be leading or trailing or some other combination, it will much more complex to fix than we can probably describe on the Internet.

The other possibility is that you simply have some bad data. In which case identify the records which are not numeric and fix them or null the value out if they cannot be fixed. This happens frequently when you have stored the data in an incorrect datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you are trying to convert data that is alphanumeric to an int and that cannot be done.

Looking at your data why are you insisting on converting it to an int when it cannot be an int? Why not just process it as an nvarchar?